# for get a ruby variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

hy

I have read à lot of question about this on stackoverflow or documentation and i didn't find my solution snif..

In my variable window.description i can see the content (window.description ="<span style="font-weight: bold;" ), he didn't display it and i dont understand why ??

```
 1.< script type="text/javascript">

           window.description  ='<%= @item.description %>';

 document.getElementById('editorResult').innerHTML = "<h2>Code display</h2><pre>" +     window.description+ "</pre>";
```

```
 <div id="editorResult">
   editorResult  =>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using @item.description.html_safe. My guess is that rails is stripping out the HTML in your description.

You are probably going to run into a few issues with escaping. Just play around with html_safe and 'escape'/'unescape'.

Comment: this doesn't work  :(  i really dont understand why he dont want to display my variable :(

Comment: What if you try <%= j @item.description.html_safe %> ? What is the output of this? the 'j' function is for [javascript escaping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript).